# How to Create a Simple kext Installer with AppleScript in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, applescript

could anyone tell me how I can create a simple installer of Kexts using AppleScrit in Xcode?
I've tried the following:

```
on installKext:sender  
choose file
copy the result to thisFile
copy the (info for thisFile) to fileInfo
copy the name extension of the fileInfo to nameExtension
copy the file type of the fileInfo to filetype
tell application "Finder"
    if the filetype is "Kext" or ¬
        the nameExtension is "Kext" then
        move thisFile to folder "Extensions" of folder "Library" of folder "System" of startup disk
    end if
end tell
end installKext:
```

I Have this errors:

> installKext:]: Not authorized to send Apple events to Finder. (error
>   -1743)
>
> Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move files with the Finder into folders which belong to the system.

You need root privileges for example with `do shell script .... with administrator privileges`

```
on installKext:sender  
    set theFile to choose file
    tell application "System Events"
        set {name extension:nameExtension, file type:fileType} to theFile
    end tell
    if fileType is "Kext" or nameExtension is "Kext" then
        do shell script "mv " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile & space & "/System/Library/Extensions/" with administrator privileges
    end if
end installKext:
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, @vadian, but even with these modifications the errors mentioned above remain, I'm creating an AppleScript application using Xcode 10.1 and the above code would run after the user clicked the "Install Kexts" button.

Comment: The error cannot be the same as the Finder is not involved anymore.

Comment: you're right, @vadian `2018-12-26 20:34:17.584052-0200 Kext Installer[3130:139843] MessageTracer: Falling back to default whitelist
2018-12-26 20:34:17.883490-0200 Kext Installer[3130:139896] [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
objc[3130]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fff88ff4210) and...`

Comment: `2018-12-26 20:34:17.584052-0200 Kext Installer[3130:139843] MessageTracer: Falling back to default whitelist
2018-12-26 20:34:17.883490-0200 Kext Installer[3130:139896] [default] Unable to load Info.plist exceptions (eGPUOverrides)
objc[3130]: Class FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework/Versions/A/FinderKit (0x7fff88ff4210)`

Comment: It seems that the error is not related to the AppleScript code.

Comment: Any idea about this problem?

Comment: Not really, sorry.

Comment: Anyway Thank you for the time and effort.

Comment: ,using your code, while adding `with multiple selections allowed` I get the following error: Can’t get «class extn» how to fix this?

Comment: `with multiple selections allowed` returns a list of files. You have to add a `repeat` loop to process one by one

Comment: An example, please.

Comment: Replace the line `set theFile to choose file` with two lines  `set allFiles to choose file with multiple selections allowed` and `repeat with theFile in allFiles`. And before the last line insert `end repeat`

Answer (score 0):

You must add the following in info.plist:
[image]
now everything works like a charm.